# Raw Types in Java

Tags: java, generics

I am working through a text book which has the following code:

```
Entry<K,V>[] tempTable = (Entry<K,V>[]) new Entry[size];
```

When I compile with `-Xlint`, it says the `Entry` on the right is missing the type arguments. However, I cannot add the type arguments, as this would lead to generic array creation. I guess my question is two-part:

1. I assume that the code in the text compiles correctly, so is there something I could do to make this work as is?
2. What is the most elegant way to do this?

Comment: I wonder if there's a problem with -Xlint.  My compiler accepts the code just fine.

Comment: `(Entry<K,V>[]) new Entry[size];` does NOT ensure the type safety. It's only a cast operation.

Comment: *"something I could do to make this work"* Are you saying you can't get this to compile? I don't really understand what you are asking for this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Entry<K,V>[] tempTable = (Entry<K,V>[]) new Entry<?,?>[size];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to use the `Collection` interface, `List` to

1- make it more elegant, and

2- get rid of the warnings

```
List<Entry<K, V>> tempTable = new  ArrayList<>();       
tempTable.add(new Entry<Integer, Double>());  // or whatever object.
```

I hope this helps.